# Group By Django queryset by a foreignkey related field

Tags: django, orm

I have a model `Allotment`

```
class Kit(models.Model):
    kit_types = (('FLC', 'FLC'), ('FSC', 'FSC'), ('Crate', 'Crate'), ('PP Box', 'PP Box'))

    kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    kit_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0, choices=kit_types, blank=True, null=True)


class AllotmentFlow(models.Model):

    flow = models.ForeignKey(Flow, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asked_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    alloted_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Allotment(models.Model):

    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dispatch_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    send_from_warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flows = models.ManyToManyField(AllotmentFlow)
```

For a stacked graph I am trying to get the data of different `kit_type` alloted in different months.
For that I have tried annotate but it isn't getting the desired results

```
dataset = Allotment.objects.all().annotate(
            month=TruncMonth('dispatch_date')).values(
            'month').annotate(dcount=Count('flows__kit__kit_type')).values('month', 'dcount')
```

Expected Output:

```
[{'month':xyz, 'kit_type':foo, count:123},...]
```

I am getting the month and count of kit type from above but how do I segregate it by `kit_type`?

Comment: An `Allotment` can have many flows and thus many kit_types, what happens in this case?

Comment: you want to group_by by `kit_type` in Kit Model?

Comment: @IainShelvington I want to get the sum of a `kit_type` alloted in a month

Comment: @mahyar Yes I want to group the data by `kit_type`

Answer (score 0):

having a field that represents your choice field names in this query is difficult
instead how about use the `Count`  filter argument and annotate to get what you want

```py
dataset = Allotment.objects.all().annotate(month=TruncMonth('dispatch_date')).values('month').annotate(
                FLC_count=Count('flows__kit__kit_type', filter=Q(flows__kit__kit_type="FLC")),
                FSC_count=Count('flows__kit__kit_type', filter=Q(flows__kit__kit_type="FSC")),
                Crate_count=Count('flows__kit__kit_type', filter=Q(flows__kit__kit_type="Crate")),
                PP_Box_count=Count('flows__kit__kit_type', filter=Q(flows__kit__kit_type="PP_Box")),
).values('month', 'FLC_count', 'FSC_count', 'Crate_count', 'PP_Box_count')
```

Comment: This would give a `dcount` error

Comment: sorry i should have changed the returning values as well. i 've edited my answer